# Multi-level databinding on UserControl menu dependant on each other

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

[image]

**I have a property `Tours` :**

- `Tours` is an `ObservableCollection` of class `Tour`

  - Each "Tour" has an `ObservableCollection` `Parties` of class `Partie`

    - Each `Partie` has an `ObservableCollection` `Equipes` of class `Equipe`

**I have 3 menus :**

1. The first is is bond with the property `Tours`
2. The second must be bond with the `SelectedItem` property of the first menu *(so it has an `ObservableCollection` of class `Partie`)*
3. The third must be bond with the `SelectedItem` property of the second menu. *(so it has an `ObservableCollection` of class `Equipes`)*

**Right  now, this is the working code :**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView Name="lvTours" ItemsSource="{Binding Tours}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Name="lvParties" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lvTours, Path=SelectedItem.Parties}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Name="lvEquipes" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lvParties, Path=SelectedItem.Equipes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

And then I can change the view of the context depending on the `SelectedItem` of the menus :

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <local:StatistiquesTour DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lvTours, Path=SelectedItem}" />
    <local:StatistiquesParties DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lvParties, Path=SelectedItem}" />
    <local:StatistiquesEquipes DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lvEquipes, Path=SelectedItem}" />            
</StackPanel>
```

My problem is if my menus becomes `Usercontrol`, I can't seem to make the `databinding` between the menu and the `ListView` (that I named : `lvMenu`) inside the `MenuUserControl`. I though it would be as simple as doing something like this :

```
<local:MenuUserControl x:Name="MenuTours" DataContext="{Binding Tours}" />
<local:MenuUserControl x:Name="MenuParties" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MenuTours.lvMenu, Path=SelectedItem}" />
<local:MenuUserControl x:Name="MenuEquipes" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MenuParties.lvMenu, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

And then the context would be reachable the same way :

```
<local:StatistiquesTour DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MenuTours.lvMenu, Path=SelectedItem}" />
<local:StatistiquesParties DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MenuParties.lvMenu, Path=SelectedItem}" />
...
```

The `lvMenu` (the `ListView`) in `MenuUserControl` has its `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` to bind it to the context.

Does anyone have a clue how to do that? (sorry for my english)

Comment: You need MVVM pattern. let me see

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe that [blog post](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html?m=1) might be the solution. It pass a `object` through `DependencyProperty`. It's seems it's harder than what I though.

Answer (score 0):

One way is DependencyProperty in the usercontrol

Another simple way is

Create a ViewModel for the MenuTours usercontrol

In MenuTours Bind ListViews selectedItem with a property in ViewModel as TwoWayBinding

Now in your main window subscribe to propertyChanged event of MenuToursViewModel

```
MenuToursViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnpropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(Sender s, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == "SelectedTour")
        {
           MenuPartiesViewModel.Items = SelectedTour.parties;
        }
    }
```

the main advantage is this code is testable and Scalable.

Hope this helps.